# How to connect to ethernet when plugging in cable?

Tags: pi-3

I have a raspberry pi 3 that is connect to my home network using wifi.

But I have another network that is LAN only.
What I want:

When I plugin the LAN cable, I want the pi to disconnect from the wifi network and connect to the LAN network. And when I remove the cable, I want it to connect back to the wifi network.

I want this solution to be permanent after reboots and shutdowns.

Comment: Why? What do you hope to achieve? Have you tried what happens?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't actually ask a question, but I assume you'd like for someone to tell you how to get "what you want". The [guidance here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) is that you're supposed to do your homework, try something, and only then ask a question. Your question reads more like a "wish"... as if you'd found the magic lamp & conjured a genie.

All that aside, your objective seems straightforward. If I were doing this, I think I would start by reading `man ip` & try to write a script that used the `ip` command to check `eth0` for a carrier. Then I would read `man wpa_cli` and/or `man rfkill` to learn how to disable the wifi. I would probably look at trying to do this using `dhcpcd` since it is the RPi *de-facto* network manager. It has *hooks* that can be run to do this sort of thing. Hopefully, that will get you started. Please don't hesitate to ask follow-on detailed questions after you've tried something.